# jquery selector on some element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a an element as shown below:

```
 <tr id="test1" class="class-of-part1">
 <td>...</td>
 </tr>
```

I have to select the the element with id 'test1' and class which begin with 'class-of'. how to select with jquery selector?

Comment: what is the need of class if you have unique id

Comment: well there are lots of tr tags generated dynamically with unique ids, I will looping through in jquery

Comment: Had you made 2 google searches with the text of your question you would have got your answer.

Comment: @sonam this will help you $("#test1[class^='class-of-']")

Comment: @sonam what are you working on now

Comment: @Sonam : if you can select elements using class name prefix, I don't think you will need any IDs..
I'd recommend you to consider redesigning your code.

Comment: There are occasions when selecting by class in addition to ID makes perfect sense, eg $('#mail-nav-button.one-or-more-messages-waiting-make-big-flashy-thing-flash')

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the [Attribute Starts With Selector (`[name^="value"]`)](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/):

```
$("#test1[class^='class-of-']")
```

Though the id *should* be unique.

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/EKBdX/)**.

Answer (score 2):

`$('#test1')` < by ID

`$('.class-of-part1')`

`$('input[class^="startofclassname"]')` < something like that

^Any input with class name starting "startofclassname"

More info: http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

Maybe try some googleing, look what i found: http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/

There you go

Comment: he said class which begin with

Answer (score 2):

What have you tried? Have you googled it?

To select the id

```
$('#test1')
```

And to select a class that begins with a string

```
$('[class^="class-of-part"]')
```

Although selecting a prefix only works on attributes, so in this case won't work if you multiple classes.

http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

Answer (score 0):

```
$('tr#test1[class^="class-of"]')
```

`tr` with `id = "test1"` and `class` starting with `"class-of"`

Answer (score 0):

All of the following will work:

```
$('#test1[class^="class-of"]');

$('#test1').filter('[class^="class-of"]');
```

Although when selecting by ID (always unique) there is no need for the class.

```
$('#test1');
```

Answer (score 0):

This might not be the `answer` OP is looking for, but I think I should inject a few basics here.

Reading through comments and the answers, reminded me of the day when I was learning jquery :)

The basing problem we all face is "We feel the desperate need for assigning IDs to every damn element".
Why?

1) Its easier to select elements using direct IDs
2) We are lazy to think how we can add event listeners to dynamically generated elements.
3) Having everything written in `.ready()` function makes it appear safe. :p

My realizations,
1) You don't need IDs for everything.

As for OP. He wants to select TRs having their class names beginning with "class-of".

OP has also specified that all the elements are generated dynamically.
So I'd recommend binding events to those TRs having class name beginning with "class-of" the same moment we create them. This will avoid lot of rework and its  a systematic approach.

My personal opinion is, add your elements to the DOM "readymade"
What I mean by "readymade" is you should not be binding events to them, or adding extra attributes or in fact, manipulating them in any way.
You should handle that before they are inserted into the DOM.
Improves performance, improves your coding skill, makes it harder for `amateurs` to understand so you retain your dependency :p lol